# Selenium take screenshot of element throws WebDriverException error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run a google search and take screenshots of the pictures that I find. For some unknown reason my web driver throws this error.

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown command: session/311d692f492d13d74fe51827ad837d4e/screenshot/0.8100675049935289-1
```

Here is the code I am using in this example I'm trying to screenshot the first image for a google search  for "Giraffe"

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://images.google.com/')
x_path = '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_path)
box.send_keys('Giraffe')
box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
element_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sf"]/div[1]/div[1]/c-wiz/c-wiz/div/a/img').screenshot('user_path/test.png')
```

I tried different methods in order to print a result. I am able to make a screenshot of the driver which is the whole page, but I want each element. I saw some solutions online using the position of each picture but that might vary since I am hoping to run many different queries.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: Using the chromedriver

Comment: Does chromedriver logs give any meaningful information about this error?

Comment: It, unfortunately, did not, but pip uninstalling selenium and reinstalling it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I modified it slightly for the latest version of selenium, find the first giraffe image using a slightly different xpath location, scroll to it so that it is visible and then take a screenshot:

```
def launch_url_screenshot(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver/chromedriver')
    driver.get(url)
    x_path = '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input'
    box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,x_path)
    box.send_keys('Giraffe')
    box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    element_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="islrg"]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/div[1]/img')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", inline: "center"})', element_2)
    element_2.screenshot('giraffe.png')
```

Called it with `launch_url_screenshot('https://images.google.com/')` and it was able to screenshot without any errors.